# Except method python pyAIML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, aiml

My AIML
pattern "HI"
bot answer "HI TOO"

My code

```
text = input.("ASK?")
if text == text:
   try:
      print(k.respond(text))
   except:
      print('NOT FOUND')
```

if i input wrong pattern like "WRONG" except massage doesnt apper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aiml will not throw any exception even if the match is not found it just replies empty string.
so instead of try and except block use if else.

```
text = input.("ASK?")
if text == text:
   if k.respond(text) != '':
      print(k.respond(text))
   else:
      print('NOT FOUND')
```